# How to Read the data from 2 sheets of same Excel document using Selenium Web driver using TestNG in Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

google home page is loaded. (Google.co.in)

```
Sheet 1 Master sheet  :   Tc_Name  & Executable are columns 
         Tc_Name   Executable
Row 1 :   Test1       No
Row 2 :   Test2       Yes  

Sheet 2 Test_Case script Sheet:Main_TC_Name & Action_search_Text are columns
          Main_TC_Name(Should be same as TC_Name of sheet 1)    Action_search_Text 
Row 1  :   Test1                                                      you
Row 2  :   Test1                                                      gmail
Row 3  :   Test2                                                      images

Sheet 3: xpath sheet : Name & xpath Name are columns 
          Name (should be same as Action_search_Text )    xpath Name 
Row 1:   you                                            //*[@id="gb"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a
Row 2 :  gmail                                         //*[@id="gb"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a
Row 3 : images                                         //*[@id="gb"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/a
```

1) Only which are in YES under Executable column from sheet 1 should be retrieved & move to sheet 2 find the same testcase name & retrieve the xpath of that from sheet 3 & then execute on front end.

For instance: 
sheet 1: Pick Test2 as its marked in Yes ---- then move to sheet 2  ----  search the Test2 instance in sheet 2 -- you ll get the Row 3 i.e images ---- then go to sheet 3 get the xpath of that--- give it on front end.

once its retrieved in front end, i want to perform Click

Comment: Selenium web driver is just Java API to interact with web browsers. it wont provide functionality to read through exel. It can be done using other Java libraries. Then pass the data to webdriver apis

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@DataProvider` annotation and define what sheet do you need for your tests.

You must create DataProvider class, name the data provider and use annotation `@Test` inside your test class.

Example:

```
@Test(testName = "test", dataProviderClass = ReturnExcelSheetData.class, dataProvider = "dataP") //dataProviderClass is optional
```

Maybe it's not direct answer to your question, but i strongly recommend using annotation. It gives you control, what test do you run, in what order, and you can adjust your @DataProvider to select 3 different excels or sheets for 3 different tests.

More direct answer would be:
Create one `@Test`, set `@DataProvider`. If data = yes, then run METHOD 1 (not test)     //example

More about TestNG: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

EDIT:

TEST CLASS:

```
public class StackOverflow extends Ustawienia {
    Logowanie page; //new constructor for login page

  @Test(testName = "test", description = "", enabled = true, dataProviderClass = StackDataProvider, dataProvider = "excel")
  public void Testing(login, password) throws Exception {
      driver.get("some random page");
      page = new Logowanie(driver, writer);
      page.methodFromLogowanieClass();
```

TestNG uses ANNOTATIONs like `@Test` to read code. For example you can use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` to set what program have to do before running proper test, and what to do after this test (for example - clean data created)

`@DataProvider` allows you to use xls or csv.

DATA PROVIDER CLASS (it's just example):

```
@DataProvider(name = "excel")
public static Object[][] returnExcelSheetData(Method method)
        throws BiffException, IOException 
        {
    String absolutePath = filePath.concat("/").concat(fileName);
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePath));
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
    Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

    int ROWS = worksheet.getRows() - 1;
    int COLS = worksheet.getColumns();

    Object[][] dataset = new Object[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < ROWS; rowCount++) {
        for (int colCount = 0; colCount < COLS; colCount++) {
            dataset[rowCount][colCount] = worksheet.getCell(colCount,
                    rowCount + 1).getContents();
        }
    }
    workbook.close();
    file.close();
    return dataset;
```

It iterates through excel sheet and returns data. If you have colums `login` and `password` as headers - it will work pretty fine. The next line (2) will be read from `@DataProvider` to `@Test` with specific `@DataProvider`.

This is my @DataProvider and i use also an interface to get data so it might not work for you. You can find plenty dataProvider examples which iterates through excel.

I hope it helped and i look forword for next questions.

Comment: I am in need of that code which works as i explained above.. please help me if possible.